# pspicture and shift option

Tags: pstricks, auto-pst-pdf

How do I successfully use the shift option of pspicture?  In former times, referring to Herbert's book from 2004, pspicture had a single optional argument which was a single number. Since 2008 one may use shift. But in my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
Test

some text
\begin{pspicture}[shift=<* or whatever number](0,0)(4,2) %\psgrid
\psframe(0,0)(3,2)
\end{pspicture}
some more 
\end{document}
```

the output is always the same, namely a frame which is aligned to the baseline.

So is there any way to align a pspicture vertically, say, center it to the baseline?  Maybe the faulty behaviour is due to auto-pst-pdf?

PS: In case it matters, I'm using  TeXlive 2016, freshly updated, on macOS.

Answer (score 2):

That cannot work with `pdflatex` and `auto-pst-pdf`. The extern created image is always placed with its lower margin on the baseline. Use the environment `postscript` or simply `xelatex` which do not needs `auto-pst-pdf`. Here is a working example with `auto-pst-pdf` and `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
    Test

\begin{postscript}  
some text
\begin{pspicture}[shift=*](0,0)(4,2) %\psgrid
    \psframe(0,0)(3,2)
\end{pspicture}
some more 
\end{postscript}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `xelatex` use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
    Test

some text
\begin{pspicture}[shift=*](0,0)(4,2) %\psgrid
    \psframe(0,0)(3,2)
\end{pspicture}
some more 

\end{document}
```